# Get Query String Values in Spring MVC Controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a referrer URL like this:

http://myUrl.com?page=thisPage&gotoUrl=https://yahoo.com?gotoPage

How do I get the Values of "page" and "gotoUrl" in my Spring Controller?

I want to store these values as variables, so I can reuse them later.

Comment: Take a look at the @RequestParam annotation.

Comment: Did you really mean to say "referer"? If so the accepted answer is wrong.

Comment: You should probably URL-encode the value of `gotoUrl` (although I'm not sure it would functionally matter in this particular example).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [getParameter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) method from the HttpServletRequest interface.

For example;

```
  public void getMeThoseParams(HttpServletRequest request){
    String page = request.getParameter("page");
    String goToURL = request.getParameter("gotoUrl");
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, if I want to pass the request as an argument. But is there a way to retrieve parameters, if I don't want to pass HttpServletRequest as an Argument to my controller action?

Comment: While this answer is technically correct, its not the recommended way to do it with Spring, @Affe's answer is more to the point.

Comment: @AkshaySinghal unless you don't know the parameters in advance but you need a way to handle them - then you can use `request.getParameterNames()` or `request.getParameterMap()`

Comment: @LukaszWiktor I'm sorry I don't understand that comment. It does not seem related to any question or answer.

Comment: @AkshaySinghal I wanted to say that Raunak's answer was helpful. In my case I don't know exact names of the parameters. I need to create an endpoint that can read any parameter. When I noticed this answer I discovered also the 2 methods mentioned in my previous comment.

Answer (score 105):

In SpringMVC you can specify values from the query string be parsed and passed in as method parameters with the @RequestParam annotation.

```
public ModelAndView getPage(
    @RequestParam(value="page", required=false) String page, 
    @RequestParam(value="gotoUrl", required = false) String gotoUrl) {
}
```

Answer (score -7):

Get the `QueryString` in Spring MVC Controller

This is Liferay portal specific solution, and it works.

Query String Example: `?reportTypeId=1&reportSeqNo=391`

In order to get the value of `reportSeqNo` in Liferay Portal, we need to get the Original Servlet Request.

```
String reportSeq = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(renderRequest)).getParameter("reportSeqNo");
```