# rest services- pass parameters in key value format

Tags: java, spring, rest

Here is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/warning/data")
public class EarlyWarningDataController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get/{soeid}/{gfcid}/{expressioncode}/{fiscalYear}/{timeperiod}", 
                method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String getEarlyWarningData(@PathVariable("soeid") String soeId,
                @PathVariable("gfcid") String[] gfcId,
                @PathVariable("expressioncode") String expressionCode,
                @PathVariable("fiscalYear") Long fiscalYear,
                @PathVariable("timeperiod") String timePeriod) throws IOException {
        sysout("");
    }
```

When I hit url

```
htpt://xyz:8080/EarlyWarning/warning/data/get/samplesoeid/1005771621/CAT_TOTAL_REV/2012/Annual
```

it works fine.

but I want to send url something like:

```
htpt://xyz:8080/EarlyWarning/warning/data/get/soeid=samplesoeid/gfcid=1005771621/expressioncode=CAT_TOTAL_REV/fiscalyear=2012/timeperiod=Annual
```

What are the changes in code do I need to do? pl help.

Answer (score 1):

You should maybe convert those parameters into `@RequestParam`, not `@PathVariable`. `@RequestParam`s are essentialy query parameters (those after the ? in the URL, divided by the &, like http://www.example.com?field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3...).

You can find the documentation here : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html

Difference between a `@PathVariable` and `@RequestParam` is discussed here: [@RequestParam vs @PathVariable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable)

Comment: I'm not really a Spring expert (I believe you are using Spring for building this), but you cannot use `@QueryParam`. It is from the JAX-RS framework, Spring utilizes `@RequestParam` which is the equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass key value data as query parameters, in the case of your example something like:

```
http://xyz:8080/Earlywarnings/warning?soeid=samplesoeid&gfcid=1005771621&expressioncode=CAT_TOTAL_REV&fiscalyear=2012&timeperiod=Annual
```

don't specifiy the method in the url, its already known.

Look at this answer for more on getting the parameters:

[Get Query String Values in Spring MVC Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934972/get-query-string-values-in-spring-mvc-controller)